# rendering datatable

Tags: datatable

I want to show the information of apex:datatable as

```
outtext1     col1
outtext2     col2
outtext3     col3
outtext4     col4
```

I could able to get colvalues but not sure how to render table like above

```
 <apex:dataTable value="{!showSAstring}" var="show" border="1" width="100%">
           <table>

               <tr><td>
           <apex:outputtext >Name</apex:outputtext><br/>
           <apex:outputtext >Zip</apex:outputtext><br/>
           <apex:outputtext >Product</apex:outputtext><br/>
           <apex:outputtext >Competency Rank</apex:outputtext><br/>
           </td>
             <td>
              <apex:column value="{!show.owner.name}" breakBefore="true"/>
              <apex:column value="{!show.Home_Zip__c}" breakBefore="true"/>
              <apex:column value="{!show.Product__c}" breakBefore="true"/> 
              <apex:column value="{!show.Competency_Rank__c}" breakBefore="true"/>
                 </td>   </tr>  
              </table>
          </apex:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

here you go

```
Name <apex:repeat value="{!showSAstring}" var="show" id="theRepeat1">
        {!show.owner.name}
    </apex:repeat>
Zip <apex:repeat value="{!showSAstring}" var="show" id="theRepeat1">
        {!show.Home_Zip__c}
    </apex:repeat>
Product<apex:repeat value="{!showSAstring}" var="show" id="theRepeat1">
        {!show.Product__c}
    </apex:repeat>
Competency Rank<<apex:repeat value="{!showSAstring}" var="show" id="theRepeat1">
        {!show.Competency_Rank__c}
    </apex:repeat>
```